# Why is my Sqlite databese not working in python?

Tags: python, database, sqlite

I've been working on a password vault the past few days. Everything works fine, but my database doesn't work. The database is created but it doesn't store the email-adresses, usernames and passwords. Anybody knows what's wrong with my code? Code below.

Also this is the error I get everytime:

```
label = Label(window, text=(array[i][1]), font=("Helvetica", 12))

IndexError: list index out of range
```

```
#Databese Code
with sqlite3.connect("password_vault.db") as db:
    cursor = db.cursor()

cursor.execute("""
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS masterpassword(
id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
password TEXT NOT NULL
)
""")

cursor.execute("""
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS vault(
id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
website TEXT NOT NULL,
username TEXT NOT NULL,
password TEXT NOT NULL
)
""")


def passwordVault():
    for widget in window.winfo_children():
        widget.destroy()

    def addEntry():
        text1 = "Website"
        text2 = "Username"
        text3 = "Password"

        website = popUp(text1)
        username = popUp(text2)
        password = popUp(text3)

        insert_fields = """INSERT INTO vault(website,username,password)
        VALUES(?, ?, ?)"""

        cursor.execute(insert_fields, (website, username, password))
        db.commit

        passwordVault()
  

   
    cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM vault")
    if (cursor.fetchall() != None):
        i = 0
        while True:
            cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM vault")
            array = cursor.fetchall()

            label = Label(window, text=(array[i][1]), font=("Helvetica", 12))
            label.grid(column=0, row=i+3)
            label = Label(window, text=(array[i][2]), font=("Helvetica", 12))
            label.grid(column=1, row=i+3)
            label = Label(window, text=(array[i][3]), font=("Helvetica", 12))
            label.grid(column=2, row=i+3)

            btn = Button(window, text="Delete", command= partial(removeEntry, array[i][0]))
            btn.grid(column=3, row=i+3, pady=10)

            i += 1

            cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM vault")
            if (len(cursor.fetchall()) <= i):
                break
```

Comment: Problem is solved, instead of db.commit(), I  typed db.commit

Answer (score 0):

It may be as simple as the fact you are using colons, not semi-colons to end your script. Python uses Semi-colons to end all functions. Not to mention, it appears there is no command for actually having those passwords, I.E. those passwords are not in your code to be accessed, as well as there is no function for the email addresses, of which you will also have to insert manually. Let me know if you need anything else.